# escape caracter ? usando funcion escape y file_get_contents($url);

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me gustaría poder escapar el caracter ? que puede ir incuido en la variable mensaje de la  cadena php
He visto la función escape de jquery

```
 var mensaje = $("#mensajeM").val(); //Hola?
 mensaje = escape(mensaje);
```

En php

```
 $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje']; //Recibo la variable ya con funcion escape 
    //En la cadena meto la variable mensaje que puede contener el ? ya escapado
 $url="http://s/ApiRest_dat/v1/_process/alta?param%5Basunto%5D=".$asunto."&param%5Bcontenido%5D=".$mensaje."&param%5Bdestinatarios%5D=".$destinatarios."&param%5Btoken%5D=".$token."&api_key=".$apiKey;
     $json = file_get_contents($url); 
     $obj = json_decode($json);
    echo json_encode($obj);
```

Si el caracter a escapar es un espacio en blanco, me lo cambia por %20 en la cadena php y todo bien, pero si el caracter a escapar es un ? No lo hace bien. Da error, al hace un echo sobre $url, la "?" me la cambia por %3F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la función (de JavaScript *puro*, **no necesita** `JQuery`) [`encodeURIComponent( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURIComponent):

```js
var uri = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURIComponent( uri );

console.log( 'Antes:', uri );
console.log( 'Después:', res );
```

> Antes: my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab
>   Después: my%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab